# TypeError: C:\nodetest1\views\userlist.jade:7

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, pug

I'm getting the above error when I try to pull my user collectionfrom my Mongodb. The relevant code is below, any help as to why this happening would be appreciated.

**Error**

```
C:\nodetest1\views\userlist.jade:7 5| User List 6| ul > 7| each user, i in userlist 8|      li 9| a(href="mailto:#{user.email}")= user.username Cannot read property 'length' of   undefined

TypeError: C:\nodetest1\views\userlist.jade:7
5|         User List
6|     ul
```

> 7|         each user, i in userlist
>       8|             li
>       9|                 a(href="mailto:#{user.email}")= user.username

```
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\nodetest1\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:172:8),   <anonymous>:50:31)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\nodetest1\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:172:8),   <anonymous>:93:4)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\nodetest1\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:172:8), <anonymous>:106:21)
at res (C:\nodetest1\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:173:38)
at Object.exports.render (C:\nodetest1\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:269:10)
at Object.exports.renderFile (C:\nodetest1\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:305:18)
at View.exports.renderFile [as engine]      (C:\nodetest1\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:290:21)
at View.render (C:\nodetest1\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:76:8)
at Function.app.render (C:\nodetest1\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:502:10)
at ServerResponse.res.render (C:\nodetest1\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:777:7)
```

**Route**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.send('respond with a resource');
});
module.exports = router;
```

users.js route

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.send('respond with a resource');
});

module.exports = router;
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('static-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// New Code
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/nodetest1');

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(favicon());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Make our db accessible to our router
app.use(function(req,res,next){
req.db = db;
next();
});

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

/// catch 404 and forwarding to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
var err = new Error('Not Found');
err.status = 404;
next(err);
});

 /// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: err
    });
});
}

 // production error handler
 // no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
res.status(err.status || 500);
res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
});
});
module.exports = app;
```

**userlist view**

```
extends layout

block content
h1.
    User List
ul
    each user, i in userlist
        li
            a(href="mailto:#{user.email}")= user.username
```

Comment: You are sending an object instead of an array i think. Try to print the userlist.

Comment: The userlist comes up when prompted in the command line so it is in the database. I just keep getting the above error when trying to see it in my browzer!

Comment: An object doesn't have a length property for instance. To print it create a script tag in your jade template that contains the userlist passed through `JSON.stringify `.then open the console in the browser.

Comment: BTW what is users route code?

Comment: I've included the users route code above!

Comment: Yeah but when do you call the template  engine ?

Comment: Am I doing that in the "// view engine setup" section in app.js?

Comment: Yeah but when does it renders it? When does it call res . render?

Comment: I fixed it, thanks for your efforts.The problem was I had not got my mongo server open as well as my node server! Silly mistake but you learn something new every day!!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, the solution is that you likely closed the connection to MongoDB, which was running in a console window in an earlier step.

Re-connect to the database with:

```
mongod --dbpath data/
```

Then run in a second console:

```
npm start
```

And direct your browser to localhost:3000 and everything should work.

This code is from the excellent [Node Tutorial by Christopher Buecheler](http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/node-express-mongo).

Comment: I made the mistake of closing the Mongodb to restart node again... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to wrong db settings (especially the port) in app.js
Make sure to have

```
var db = monk('localhost:27017/nodetest1')
```

matching your mongod port

```
2014-12-15T23:19:23.032+0200 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```